# special symbol of H

Tags: symbols

I wish to write `H` as below form:

[image]

But I do not know what is its symbol in the latex!

If anyone has experience using this symbol, thanks for providing it.

Comment: `mt` Mathtime Pro 2 script...

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question.

Are you happy with this (using `stix` package):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\begin{document}
A script k in maths $\mathscr H$
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]